# How to get a list of security updates on the command line in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, command-line-interface, apt

In the GUI tool you can get a list packages with security updates. Can this be done on the command line in Debian or Ubuntu?

Normally I might use "apt-get upgrade" which would show me what is being upgraded, but I would like to know which ones are security updates.

Comment: just for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04 LTS: https://askubuntu.com/a/1128270/92504

Comment: Such a simple and frequent task and not a single functional (out of the box, at least) or standard way of doing it... Yay! Linux is amazing! Not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the unattended-upgrade application.

```
sudo unattended-upgrade
```

This lets you install only security updates automatically, but you can call it manually if needed.

Comment: I like this answer as you've actually thought about what I might be trying to do and unattended-upgrade is something I've installed today to try out.

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the question though.

Comment: If this is the answer, then the question was wrong.  At the least, it evolved, and should be edited accordingly and/or marked as a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line

Comment: My Debian `apt` repository only lists a `unattended-upgrades` (plural) package. Was that package renamed or what?

Comment: Ah! The package name is in plural and calling it is in singular... Weird.

Answer (score 45):

```
apt-get upgrade -s | grep -i security
```

... is what the Nagios check-apt plugin uses to count pending security updates which is similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: But it cannot find bash security update for shellshock?

Comment: This gives false positives on packages with "security" in the name, such as "xml-security-c-utils", "debian-security-support", "modsecurity-crs", "node-security", etc.

Comment: @Shnatsel for a command line check, it's very easy... you can easily see whether it's a false positive or not. Also if you know the current name of your OS, you could write `grep -i xenial-security` and it should reduce the false positive to pretty much zero.

Comment: @Shnatsel so `grep Debian-Security` would be a better solution?

Comment: This is useful for getting the number of `regular;security` updates available.  The `-p` option to list the package names available for update does not distinguish between regular and security updates however (at least on 16.04)...so this is not a viable way to get a list of security updates available as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 11):

On ubuntu you should be able to use apt-check, it's the one that populates your motd with the number of security updates available.

Comment: I can't see that on debian or ubuntu.

Comment: apt-check is in /usr/lib/update-notifier/.  Try /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable for a straightforward message.

Comment: I'm not convinced that shows anything useful. To get the list, you need to add `--package-names` (`-p`), but then it doesn't seem to differentiate between regular updates and security updates.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list with this command:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d 2> /dev/null | grep 'Checking' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: You sent ALL output to `/dev/null` so you won't be grepping anything!

Comment: This seems doesn't work with trusty. it shows all packages that need update instead.

Comment: I guess it would show you what unattended-upgrade was going to do, and if you'd configured it to only do security updates, maybe this recipe would work.  The answer though is at best woefully incomplete.

Comment: Today I solved this need modifying a little bit apt-check. Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/thesp0nge/94f9d336a081a3fefba6ca61d787a28b

Answer (score 3):

I have a modified version of `update-notifier` that takes an additional switch: `--security-package-names` which outputs only the security related package names. I have it as a gist (until I create a merge request in the relevant project in launchpad). Until then it can be run as follows:

**Run**

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ahmadnazir/c2444d6b09fd7bb4963a13bc577d92a3/raw/0231b94a4e46abe0a5959de5f84feda76ad2eb9d/apt-check.py \
  | python /dev/stdin --security-package-names \
  | column -t -s , \
  | sort
```

**Output**

This gives an output of the format: **package name**, **installed version**, and **candidate version**:

```
...
thunderbird                          1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-gnome-support            1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-locale-en                1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
thunderbird-locale-en-us             1:38.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Fabrizio Regini's answer above.

For 12.04 / Precise:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d 2>&1 /dev/null | grep 'Checking' | grep security | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

For 14.04 /Trusty:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d | grep 'Checking' | grep security | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

And a variant clobbered together after reading the other responses - I believe this to cater to the false positive issue, and be reasonably lightweight.

```
sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d 2>/dev/null  | awk '/Checking/ && /archive:..*-security. / {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Answering the question the OP asks is how to see the *List* of packages, and not how to install only security packages. Building on the answer of @topdog You should use:

`/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p`

Where the `-p` flag stands for packages

Comment: this lists all packages and not only security updates

Comment: apt-check seems unavailable in Debian Jessie. It remains on updated Wheezy-systems but fresh installs don't have the update-notifier-common anymore. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: @jan it's still there, as part of  `update-notifier-common`

Comment: @Auspex That package does no longer exist in Jessie. There is only `update-notifier` which is an outdated transitional package for `gnome-packagekit`. See [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/update-notifier).

Comment: @jan Sorry, I took debian's word for it. I searched for the file, https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=apt-check&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any and it told me `You have searched for files named apt-check in suite jessie, all sections, and all architectures. Found 1 results.`, but then when you actually click on the link for that result, it tells you `Package not available in this suite.`

Comment: @Auspex No problem, sounds like something that could be reported as a bug for the Debian page.

Answer (score 0):

These two commands will spit out the list. Pipe to wc -l to see how many are behind. ;-)

```
grep security /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/security.list
sudo apt-get upgrade -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/tmp/security.list -s
```

Still valid for older distros or if you have update repos off, but security on:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -s| grep ^Inst |grep Security
```

Comment: Be careful.  If you generate /tmp/security.list this way while running as root, then you are vulnerable to a symlink based attack.

Comment: I can't get this approach (the first code block) on Ubuntu 14.04.  The `-oDir::Etc::Sourcelist` option doesn't seem to disable the standard set of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I think @smin 's answer is basically a good approach, but a bit loose with the regex, as noted by @Shnatsel.

How about this:

```
apt-get upgrade -q --dry-run \
| perl -ne 'm/^Inst (\S+) \S+ \(([^\)]+) Debian-Security:8/ && print "$1-$2\n"'
```

This lists the package names along with the versions you want to install.  You can take `-$2` out of the print statement if you don't want the versions there.

[This could probably be made just a little lighter-weight by using awk instead of perl]

Answer (score 0):

I solved modifying the apt-check script on my Ubuntu system. It takes care only about security updates, displaying also package names if -p flag it has been provided.

You can find the gist here: https://gist.github.com/thesp0nge/94f9d336a081a3fefba6ca61d787a28b